# Error installed 'wdm' gem on Windows system

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I have a fresh install of Ruby 2.2.1 (32-bit) on my Windows 7 system.  I also installed the devkit without any reported errors.  Naturally I thought I could just install the 'wdm' gem with:

```
gem install wdm
```

However, it errors out.  The entire output is a bit much to post the entire thing so truncated the following points come up.

```
C:/Ruby22/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20150318-1712-oq5nlb.rb extconf.rb
checking for main() in -lkernel32... yes
checking for windows.h... yes
checking for ruby.h... yes
checking for HAVE_RUBY_ENCODING_H... yes
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
generating wdm_ext-i386-mingw32.def
compiling entry.c
In file included from entry.c:1:0:
wdm.h:3:0: warning: "WINVER" redefined [enabled by default]
...
wdm.h:4:0: warning: "_WIN32_WINNT" redefined [enabled by default]
...
warning: #warning Please include winsock2.h before windows.h [-Wcpp]
compiling monitor.c  (this is repeated for multiple *.c files)
...
rb_monitor.o: In function `rb_monitor_run_bang':
C:\Ruby22\lib\ruby\gems\2.2.0\gems\wdm-0.1.0\ext\wdm/rb_monitor.c:508: undefined reference to `rb_thread_blocking_region'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [wdm_ext.so] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: wdm isn't compatible with 2.2 ([`rb_thread_blocking_region()` was removed](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_2_1/NEWS#L263-L294))

Comment: @cremno, that would explain it.  Thanks, if you want to post as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `wdm` gem isn't compatible with 2.2. It calls the function `rb_thread_blocking_region()` which was deprecated in 2.0 and finally [removed in 2.2](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v2_2_0/NEWS#L263-L294). Also the gem isn't maintained anymore (see its [repository and issue tracker](https://github.com/Maher4Ever/wdm)).

<s>You could fork the repo, merge [the  existing PR that apparently fixes the issue](https://github.com/Maher4Ever/wdm/pull/16), and build the gem by yourself. Using an older Ruby version could be a solution too.</s>

**Update:**
The `wdm` gem was updated to [0.1.1](https://rubygems.org/gems/wdm/versions/0.1.1) a while ago. The error is fixed by this version.

Comment: Just make sure the Ruby and DevKit releases match. For example, Ruby 1.9.3 and DevKit 4.5.2-20111229.

Comment: The gem is now being maintained again and this issue might be solved by https://github.com/Maher4Ever/wdm/issues/18